# how to get the Id from the URL while using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am quite new to `Javascript` and `node.js` and I'm trying to create a `REST API`, and the urls will be of the form.

1. `/user/{userId}/docs`

I am trying to get the value of `{userId}`, which in the case of `/user/5/docs` will be `5`.

I could try to pass this as a request parameter(in the querystring or in the body, depending on the `GET` or `POST` method), but the url looks more intuitive when it is formed this will. Plus there are many more urls which are like these.

I am wondering if there are any node modules like express which provide for this.

I am a traditional `Java` user and `Jersey` framework used to provide such a thing in `Java`.

Thanks,
Tuco

Comment: Yes, the Express module provides this.

Comment: Hi Johnny, can you please provide an example.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Spend some time with [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).  Express uses the `:` to denote a variable in a route:

```
app.get('/user/:id/docs', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Write the following in the server script:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var url = request.url; //this will be /user/5/docs
    url.id = url.split("/")[2]; // this will be 5
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
    response.end("Id is = " + url.id);
});
server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: I noticed this also, when I `split('/')`, I get an array with first and last indexes as empty strings...why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
var id = pathName.split("=");
var userId = id[1];
```